# Lenovo Ideapad S205 Wireless LAN problem

Tags: wireless, ndiswrapper

I've a problem with Lenovo S205 AMD E-450 processor, Ubuntu 12.04 and wireless LAN.

If I install by Windows Wireless Driver utilities a driver named `netathrx.inf` I get error message:

```
Module could not be loaded. Error was:

WARNING: /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad_laptop.conf line 6: ignoring bad line
starting with 'echo'
WARNING: /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad_laptop.conf line 12: ignoring bad line
starting with 'echo'
FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found.

Is the ndiswrapper module installed?
```

Yes, the ndiswrapper module is installed.

How to get wifi work properly?

Comment: Yesterday, after doing something in terminal, 'rfkill list' didn't show wireless adapter anymore I formatted and put 11.10 on laptop. Somewhere in the Internet I found **acer_wmi** is the problem, needs to be *blacklisted*. Voila  :) it works, no need to install anydrivers